# How to compute attgt by region using did package in R

Tags: function, r-package, economics

I am trying to compute the group time average treatment effects by region rewriting the compute.att_gt function of the did package. I have a dataset called mpdta1. Here is the dataset:

```
  year State countyreal first.treat treat_group  emp pop     lemp     lpop rel_year
1 2003    CO       8001        2007           1 4729 364 8.461469 5.897154       -4
2 2004    CO       8001        2007           1 4175 364 8.336870 5.897154       -3
3 2005    CO       8001        2007           1 4189 364 8.340217 5.897154       -2
4 2006    CO       8001        2007           1 4351 364 8.378161 5.897154       -1
5 2007    CO       8001        2007           1 4304 364 8.367300 5.897154        0
6 2003    CO       8019        2007           1  148   9 4.997212 2.197225       -4
```

idname=countyreal, gname=first.treat, yname=lemp.

I have tried to write the following function

```
dp <- list(
  data = mpdta1,  # Replace with your actual data
  yname = "lemp",
  tname = "year",
  idname = "countyreal",
  xformla = ~lpop,  # Specify the correct formula here
  weightsname = NULL,
  est_method = "dr",
  base_period = "varying",
  panel = TRUE,
  true_repeated_cross_sections = FALSE,
  print_details = TRUE,
  control_group = c("nevertreated","notyettreated"),
  anticipation = 0,
  gname = "first.treat",
  n = 500,
  nT = 5,
  nG = 3,
  tlist = c(2003,2004,2005,2006,2007),
  glist = c(2004,2006,2007)
)

regions<-unique(mpdta1$State)

compute.att_gt_regions <- function(dp, regions) {
  
  # Initialize list to store attgt values by regions
  attgt_regions <- list()
  
  # Loop over regions
  for (region in regions) {
    # Subset the data for the current region
    dp$data <- subset(dp$data, region == region)
    
    # Compute attgt using the modified compute.att_gt function
    attgt <- compute.att_gt(dp)
    
    # Add the attgt result to the list for the current region
    attgt_regions[[region]] <- attgt
  }
  
  # Return the attgt values by regions
  return(attgt_regions)
}
att_byregions<-compute.att_gt_regions(dp,regions)
```

The problem is that when I use this function to compute the attgt, I get the effects also for the periods in which the region is not treated.
For Example Colorado is firstly treated in 2007, so I would like to have att(2007,2004),att(2007,2006) etc. and not also att(2006,2004). This is what I am talking:

```
[[1]]
[[1]]$att
[1] -0.0145622

[[1]]$group
[1] 2004

[[1]]$year
[1] 2004

[[1]]$post
[1] 1


[[2]]
[[2]]$att
[1] -0.0868768

[[2]]$group
[1] 2004

[[2]]$year
[1] 2005

[[2]]$post
[1] 1


[[3]]
[[3]]$att
[1] -0.1455338

[[3]]$group
[1] 2004

[[3]]$year
[1] 2006

[[3]]$post
[1] 1


[[4]]
[[4]]$att
[1] -0.1069901

[[4]]$group
[1] 2004

[[4]]$year
[1] 2007

[[4]]$post
[1] 1


[[5]]
[[5]]$att
[1] -0.0005143208

[[5]]$group
[1] 2006

[[5]]$year
[1] 2004

[[5]]$post
[1] 0


[[6]]
[[6]]$att
[1] -0.006248141

[[6]]$group
[1] 2006

[[6]]$year
[1] 2005

[[6]]$post
[1] 0


[[7]]
[[7]]$att
[1] -0.01932826

[[7]]$group
[1] 2006

[[7]]$year
[1] 2006

[[7]]$post
[1] 1


[[8]]
[[8]]$att
[1] -0.06469874

[[8]]$group
[1] 2006

[[8]]$year
[1] 2007

[[8]]$post
[1] 1


[[9]]
[[9]]$att
[1] 0.02673521

[[9]]$group
[1] 2007

[[9]]$year
[1] 2004

[[9]]$post
[1] 0


[[10]]
[[10]]$att
[1] -0.004571964

[[10]]$group
[1] 2007

[[10]]$year
[1] 2005

[[10]]$post
[1] 0


[[11]]
[[11]]$att
[1] -0.02843186

[[11]]$group
[1] 2007

[[11]]$year
[1] 2006

[[11]]$post
[1] 0


[[12]]
[[12]]$att
[1] -0.04752267

[[12]]$group
[1] 2007

[[12]]$year
[1] 2007

[[12]]$post
[1] 1
```

I would like to have something like this for each region:

```
 Group Time ATT(g,t) Std. Error [95% Simult.  Conf. Band]  
  2004 2004  -0.0146     0.0238       -0.0782      0.0491  
  2004 2005  -0.0869     0.0303       -0.1681     -0.0056 *
  2004 2006  -0.1455     0.0421       -0.2583     -0.0328 *
  2004 2007  -0.1070     0.0338       -0.1976     -0.0164 *
  2006 2004  -0.0005     0.0233       -0.0630      0.0619  
  2006 2005  -0.0062     0.0193       -0.0579      0.0454  
  2006 2006  -0.0193     0.0192       -0.0708      0.0321  
  2006 2007  -0.0647     0.0186       -0.1145     -0.0149 *
  2007 2004   0.0267     0.0138       -0.0102      0.0636  
  2007 2005  -0.0046     0.0156       -0.0464      0.0372  
  2007 2006  -0.0284     0.0178       -0.0761      0.0192  
  2007 2007  -0.0475     0.0137       -0.0841     -0.0109 *
```

How can I do this?